# prototypeJS DOM and AJAX interaction

Tags: javascript, dom, prototypejs

I have a conceptual DOM question - I hope it makes sense.

My page (call it 'Main') has the prototypeJS AJAX Updater on it, I'm selecting a record to edit and that calls a 'page B' (a partial) into a div on the 'Main' page.

When I click on the form in the partial, it calls the function on the 'Main' - however the Updater is "Supposed To" update a div on the partial... but it never does. I'm pretty sure the DOM cant find it because it was rendered or brought into the Main...

How do I solve this???

**MAIN**

```
<script>
// pulls page B into Main div
function getItem( id ) {
    var url = 'itemDetails.php'; 
    var pars = { id:id };
    var myAjaxOpts = new Ajax.Updater( 'itemDetail', url, {
            method:'post'
            ,parameters:pars
            ,evalScripts:true
        });
}

// post form and expects messages in 2 places (1) the upated div (on page B) and the message div on Main
// Only main showing up
function assignItem( frm ) {
    var url = 'assignItem.php'; 
    var pars = Form.serialize( frm );
    var myAjaxOpts = new Ajax.Updater( 'subMessage', url, {
            method:'post'
            ,parameters:pars
            ,evalScripts:true
            ,onSuccess: function( response ){
                //console.log( 'request ready to be made' );
                $( 'mainMessage' ).update( response );
            }
        });
}
</script>   

<!-- page A - Main -->
<div id="mainMessage"></div>
<ul>
    <li><a onClick="getItem( 1 );">item 1</a></li>
    <li><a onClick="getItem( 2 );">item 2</a></li>
    <li><a onClick="getItem( 3 );">item 3</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="itemDetail"></div>
<!-- end page A -->
```

**Page B (the partial)**

```
<!-- page B - Partial -->
<div id="subMessage"></div>
<form>
    -- edit record ---
<input type="button" onClick="assignItem( this.form );" ></form>
<!-- end page B -->
```

BTW - it should be noted that this is a 'reduced' sample (and may have typos), I'm getting the data back as expected, there are no issues with the AJAX, it's simply that the div IN the partial doesn't seem to be available to the function on the Main.

Thx

Comment: Have you tried it without wrapping the partial page in a `<body>` tag? just outputting the "naked" div? Because that puts a `<body>` tag in the middle of the page its invalid HTML and the javascript might barf on that.

Comment: sry Geek... that is there just as example - I'll take it out - but currently - it's just a table that is returned...

Comment: Are there any error messages? Please debug your application to find out what part of it exactly does not work. Is `assignItem` called? Is the second ajax request sent and received? Is the `onSuccess` callback executed? How does the DOM look like at that moment? Does it work without the first ajax updater?

Answer (score 0):

Just change the id where you're update.

change this :`$( 'mainMessage' ).update( response );`

by : `$( 'subMessage' ).update( response );`